# Deploy flask application with fastcgi and Apache under Windows

Tags: apache, python-2.7, flask, fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy my flask app on apache, using fastcgi.

OS: Windows 10
python 2.7

apache path: E:\development\webservices\apache\bin\httpd.exe

Python path: C:\Python27\python.exe

I'm using mod mod_fcgid 2.3.9 for running fastcgi (E:\development\webservices\apache\modules\mod_fcgid.so)

My fastcgi conf(E:\development\webservices\apache\conf\extra\httpd-fastcgi.conf)

```
FcgidInitialEnv PATH "e:/development/webservices/php;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;C:/Python27/;C:/Python27/Scripts;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidIOTimeout 64
FcgidConnectTimeout 16
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000 
FcgidMaxProcesses 50 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 8131072
# Location php.ini:
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "e:/development/webservices/php"
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000

<Files ~ "\.php$>"
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper "e:/development/webservices/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Files>
```

My httpd.conf:

```
Listen 5000
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
# FastCGI
Include conf/extra/httpd-fastcgi.conf
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerName localhost:5000
    DocumentRoot c:/myproject/app
    ScriptAlias / c:/myproject/app/runserver.fcgi/

<Directory "c:/myproject/app/">
   AllowOverride None
   Allow from all
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My flask application lies here: C:\myproject\app

It has the following structure:

```
app\
    runserver.py
    runserver.fcgi
    gallery\
    image_hosting\
                   images\
                   static\
                           css\
                           jmg\
                           js\
                   templates\
                   init.py
                   forms.py
                   models.py
                   routes.py
```

runserver.fcgi contents:

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from image_hosting import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

When I try to acess localhost:5000 I get the 500 Internal Server Error

Apache error log:

```
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::680d:ad2a:63e8:99bd. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:20.405465 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20032:tid 668] AH00455: Apache/2.4.20 (Win64) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:20.405465 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20032:tid 668] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Apr  5 2016 13:15:28
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:20.405465 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20032:tid 668] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\development\\webservices\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/development/webservices/apache'
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:20.406460 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20032:tid 668] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3788
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::680d:ad2a:63e8:99bd. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::680d:ad2a:63e8:99bd. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:20.702847 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3788:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:21.444860 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7552:tid 652] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:28.178274 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3788:tid 1172] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : [client ::1:56818] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Mon Apr 18 12:36:28.178274 2016] [core:error] [pid 3788:tid 1172] [client ::1:56818] End of script output before headers: runserver.fcgi
```

Can somebody explain to me, what seems to be the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, flup does not support Windows. That was really silly of me.